# Zooming to extent of filtered vector layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a vector layer that I need to filter and zoom to extent of the layer whilst the filter is applied. Most of the examples I see only zoom to selected features. I have managed to filter using

```
p_id = 31
filter_rule = ' id = %s ' % p_id
qExp = QgsExpression(filter_rule)
qReq = QgsFeatureRequest(qExp)
features = layer.getFeatures(qReq)
```

How can I zoom to the extent to only show the feature which corresponds to the filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to filter the features using the [setSubsetString()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aba0ee124dcf2d037f3af53d99866c01c) method. Once your layer is filtered, you can then set the canvas extent which is only affected by the remaining features of the layer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()

p_id = 31
filter_rule = ' id = %s ' % p_id    
layer.setSubsetString(filter_rule)  
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
```